# Is there a way to figure out the font that a template is using?

Tags: fonts

So, I am using a LaTeX-Template (`\documentclass{template of my institute}`) and I want to figure out what font is being used (both the name and the size), so that I can use the same font in a figure that I am creating. I think the font is probably specified somewhere in the .log file. However, can anyone tell me what specifically I need to look for and how to find it?

Comment: If you check the pdf properties from the pdf viewer, you can see the fonts.

Comment: You can also look at the class file to see which font packages are loaded (you will have to know which ones are font packages though). If you happen to be using Inkscape, you would like to know that Inkscape can export images to LaTeX so that the font is the same as in the document.

Comment: you can use `\expandafter\show\the\font` at any point (there is a duplicate question about that somewhere) but note if you are using pdftex or tex (as opposed to luatex or xetex) the font encodings are specific to tex and using the fonts in another application may not be trivial.